# Google reCaptcha not displaying properly

Tags: recaptcha

I set up a captcha using Googles reCaptcha on my Sites contact page and this works fine with no issues.

The actual contact form itself is a seperate php file that I just include on my contact page.

However, I want to add a contact form to the footer on my site as well so I have included the contact form file there as well.

However, the recaptcha does not appear in the footer contact section, except when I am on the contact page.

I thought maybe I had to specify a URL that it was on in Googles settings but it only seems to have an option to specify the domain but it is obviously on the same domain.

Any ideas of why this would be happening or how I can resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake...

Only had included the script tag on the page where I already had the form.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```